# Options for refreshing a Power Bi after running a Python Script

Tags: python, automation, powerbi

I have a python script that basically goes to sharepoint grabs some files, does some stuff and uploads some tables to a aws database.

And I wanted to create a next step that after that it updates a specific Power BI, but I am struggling with that next step. I am not finding much info related to code that updates a specific Power BI.

Does anyone with more knowledge might point me out to a good solution? One of my first thoughts was to use Power Automate, but Power Automate cloud doesn't run python scripts.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Power BI Rest API to refresh a dataset.
[Microsoft Docs - Power BI API Refresh Dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refresh-dataset)

Only the authentication is a bit tricky with Python.

One other solution could be to use PowerShell inside of an Azure Function and use the Powershell to invoke a API Call. Adam from Guy in a Cube created a good video on Youtube how to do this:
[Follow this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBTQ3CFstzs)